# Add html to string svelte

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

Hey I have a couple strings of text

```html
let text = [
    "<strong>Voiijer</strong>" +
      "is a global community of explorers of all ages who create and share expeditions",
    "Everyone is an explorer, now everyone can explore. Voiijer is for everyone, from students to scientists.",
    "Voiijer is for the naturally curious. <br />To tell the story of the world.",
  ];
```

that I am displaying like this

```html
<p>{text[index]}</p>
```

with the index being the index of the carousal element but the html elements are just displaying as text. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

You can show it with `{@html text[index]}`

However, according to the [docs](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/html-tags):

> Svelte doesn't perform any sanitization of the expression inside {@html ...} before it gets inserted into the DOM. In other words, if you use this feature it's critical that you manually escape HTML that comes from sources you don't trust, otherwise you risk exposing your users to XSS attacks.

You should make sure your string is safe by yourself.

Comment: Thanks man worked! But what are XSS attacks?

Comment: That is a whole another topic, you can Google it and you will find plenty of material. If your application is just to learn or have some fun it's fine, if it's for something that will be sold or used commercially, you should get more information about Cross-Site Scripting.